# Quoting a complex awk program in tmux.conf

Tags: awk, escaping, tmux, gawk, quoting

A user on Freenode #tmux asked:

1. How can we properly escape this shell command using GNU awk for `set -g tmux status-right`?

   ```
   sensors | awk '/^Physical id 0:/ { s = $4; sub(/^+/, "", s); print s; exit }'
   ```

   The result should be `45.0°C`.
2. Also, how can we make it update every 30 seconds?

The output of `sensors`:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Setting status-right

#### Quoting with shell command `#( )` in tmux

Quoting is complex in tmux `#( )` because the contents are [evaluated twice](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-proper-way-to-escape-characters-with-command).

For this reason let's simplify the gawk program to:

```
sensors | awk '/^Physical id 0:/ { sub(/^+/, "", $4); print $4; exit }'
```

Now we plug it into `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g status-right "#( sensors | awk \\' /Physical id 0:/ {  sub\\(/\+/,\"\",$4\\); print \$4; exit }  \\')"
```

But that's terribly complex to read and change next time you go tinkering...

#### An easier alternative

The easiest solution is to put the shell command into a file and call it from tmux.

~/bin/tmux-status.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
sensors | awk '/^Physical id 0:/ { sub(/^+/, "", $4); print $4; exit }'
```

~/.tmux.conf:

```
set-option -g status-right "#(bash ~/bin/tmux-status.bash)"
```

#### Make it update every 30 seconds

```
set-option -g status-interval 30
```

## See also

- [tmux titles-string not executing shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264679/tmux-titles-string-not-executing-shell-command), StackOverflow
- ["What is the proper way to escape characters with #(command)?"](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-proper-way-to-escape-characters-with-command), tmux FAQ on github

Comment: The `exit` in the awk script is probably worth not dropping (though it depends on how large the output from `sensors` is and where that line appears in it).

Comment: @EtanReisner, true, true... in this case it was a short file. I've submitted an edit to put it back in.